# Create panels in a rectangular area which have rectangular openings

Tags: geometry, optimization

Suppose we have a rectangular area in which there is the number of rectangular openings present. I want to fill an area with panels which are not under the opening area.

See the below image for better understanding.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbpVr.jpg)

Below are the rules which should be followed while creating panels:

- Panel length and width shall not greater than 2.2 meters.
- Panels should be always less in number.

Any idea that how to address this problem?

Comment: Please provide some more context, do you want to maximize the filled area?

Comment: @Mefitico The region to be covered is specified, so it isn't a question of maximizing the area (which is fixed) but of minimizing the number of panels.